# Why were leap years decided only by judges and not with the cooperation of witnesses?

Tags: halacha, calendar, rosh-chodesh-new-month

[Ramba"m Hilchot Kiddush Hachodesh 4:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/947921/jewish/Kiddush-HaChodesh-Chapter-Four.htm) says:

> The year can be made full only by [judges] who were invited [to
>   participate in the deliberations]. What is implied? The head of the
>   High Court tells [several] members of the court, "Be present at a
>   particular place, where we will make calculations and decide whether
>   or not it is necessary to make the year full" It is only those who
>   were invited who [have the authority to] make [the year] full.

The sanctification of each month required witnesses to appear (although, if they did not appear, Sanhedrin could declare Rosh Hodesh, themselves. However, that was not the first option.)

How come witness / populace input was not used to decide on the declaration of leap years?

Comment: What would they testify to seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Each new month was declared because the new moon was sighted by witnesses. Thus, bais din was required to have the witnesses testify. The leap year was determined by analysis of the facts put before bais din, such as the crops, the relationship of the solar position to the current calendar, etc.That is, witnesses would be required to establish the facts being put before bais din. This is sufficient to determine the new month. However, once the facts of the case had been established, the leap year required expert analysis of those facts. For this, witnesses were not sufficient. In fact, that is why only those who were sufficiently expert would be invited to assist in the deliberations.

Comment: The question was "How come witness / populace input was not used to decide on the declaration of leap years?" and you're contending that it was in fact: "witnesses would be required to establish the facts". That's a great answer, but do you have any evidence to support it?